# subscribing two observables i.e. observable inside another observable HTTP

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to angular. I am trying to post and get data at a time. I am using `map` and subscribing the observable while the outer observable is subscribed in component.

```js
add(data) {
  return this.postModel(`pathHere`, data)
  .pipe(map((resp) => {
    if(resp.models){
      return this.getRoomById(resp.models.id).subscribe();
    }
  }));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to use `flatMap` instead of `map` as

```js
add(data) {
  return this.postModel(`pathHere`, data)
  .pipe(flatMap((resp) => {
    if(resp.models){
      return this.getRoomById(resp.models.id);
    }
  }));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
add(data) {
    return this.postModel(`pathHere`, data)
        .pipe(
            switchMap((resp) => {
                if (resp.models) {
                    return this.getRoomById(resp.models.id);
                }
                  return of(resp.models);
            })
        );
}
```

You can use `switchMap` to emit another `Observable`.

As you used `if` statement for checking `resp.models`, you have to handle the case when `resp.models` is not truthy.